# how to make particular cell editable in tabulator

Tags: javascript, angular, tabulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WLRl.png)

[needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLfFU.png)

```js
initializeTabulatortableBng() {
  let classThis = this;
  let bngTableData = classThis.tableDataWorm;

  function decimalFormatter(cell) {
    var value = cell.getValue();
    if (value !== null && value !== undefined && !isNaN(value)) {
      return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    }
    return value;
  }
  this.bngTabulatorHeaders = [{
      title: "Type",
      field: "name",
      headerHozAlign: "left",
      width: 600,
      headerSort: false,
      hozAlign: "left",
      editable: false
    },
    {
      title: "Value",
      headerHozAlign: "center",
      width: 900,
      columns: [{
          title: "Min",
          field: "minValue",
          editor: false,
          headerSort: false,
          width: 300,
          hozAlign: "right",
          formatter: decimalFormatter,
          headerHozAlign: "right",
          editorParams: {
            formatter: decimalFormatter
          },
        },
        {
          title: "Nom",
          field: "nomValue",
          editor: "input",
          headerSort: false,
          width: 300,
          hozAlign: "right",
          formatter: decimalFormatter,
          headerHozAlign: "right",
          editorParams: {
            formatter: decimalFormatter
          }
        },
        {
          title: "Max",
          field: "maxValue",
          editor: false,
          headerSort: false,
          width: 300,
          hozAlign: "right",
          formatter: decimalFormatter,
          headerHozAlign: "right",
          editorParams: {
            formatter: decimalFormatter
          }
        },
      ],
    },

  ];
  this.bngTabulatorTable = new Tabulator("#bngTabulatorTable", {
    maxHeight: "100%",
    maxwidth: "100%",
    data: bngTableData,
    layout: "fitColumns",
    headerSort: false,
    columns: this.bngTabulatorHeaders,
  })
}
```

here i want to enable edit for nom full column i have done that its working and i want make editable cell Efficiency [-] row means min column first cell i.e 0.91 here and Servo Stiffness (axial) row -min column 5th cell i,e 0.00 means Efficiency [-] & Servo Stiffness (axial) rows should be editable ``

Comment: some one please check this its urgent

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: from the second image -- which is marked as [needed]  here all the grey marked cells in max,min,nom columns should be non editable and white colored cells should be editable cells i wanted

Comment: let me know if its clarify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding it correctly, you want to make certain cells editable based on a Type value. If that's the case, you need to change the editor type of Min and Max to `input` and also add an `editable` callback to those columns to determine if they should be editable or not.  See below commented lines:

```js
// Function to check if the cell should be editable:
function editCheck(cell) {
  const data = cell.getRow().getData()
     
  return data.name === 'Efficiency [-]' || data.name === 'Servo Stiffness (axial)'
}

initializeTabulatortableBng() {
  this.bngTabulatorHeaders = [
    {
      title: 'Type',
      field: 'name',
      headerHozAlign: 'left',
      width: 600,
      headerSort: false,
      hozAlign: 'left',
      editable: false
    },
    {
      title: 'Value',
      headerHozAlign: 'center',
      width: 900,
      columns: [
        {
          title: 'Min',
          field: 'minValue',
          editor: 'input', // <<<<  Change editor to input
          editable: editCheck, // <<<< Add editable callback
          headerSort: false,
          width: 300,
          hozAlign: 'right',
          formatter: decimalFormatter,
          headerHozAlign: 'right',
          editorParams: {
            formatter: decimalFormatter
          }
        },
        {
          title: 'Nom',
          field: 'nomValue',
          editor: 'input',
          headerSort: false,
          width: 300,
          hozAlign: 'right',
          formatter: decimalFormatter,
          headerHozAlign: 'right',
          editorParams: {
            formatter: decimalFormatter
          }
        },
        {
          title: 'Max',
          field: 'maxValue',
          editor: 'input', // <<<<  Change editor to input
          editable: editCheck,  // <<<< Add editable callback
          headerSort: false,
          width: 300,
          hozAlign: 'right',
          formatter: decimalFormatter,
          headerHozAlign: 'right',
          editorParams: {
            formatter: decimalFormatter
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a basic example of how that works:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Billy Bob', age: '12', gender: 'male', height: 1, col: 'red', dob: '', cheese: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May', age: '1', gender: 'female', height: 2, col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982', cheese: true },
  { id: 10, name: 'Margret Marmajuke', age: '16', gender: 'female', height: 5, col: 'yellow', dob: '31/01/1999' }
]

function editCheck(cell) {
  const data = cell.getRow().getData()
  
  const isEditable = data.name === 'Mary May' || data.name === 'Billy Bob'
  
  if (!isEditable) {
    cell.setValue('')
    cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#ccc"
  }
  
  return isEditable
}

const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
  data: data,
  columns: [
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name'},
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age', editor:'input', editable: editCheck  },
    { title: 'Gender', field: 'gender' },
    { title: 'Height', field: 'height' },
    { title: 'Color', field: 'col' }
  ]
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="table"></div>
```

You can also read more about it here: https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/edit#optional

Comment: thanks its working fine but i want to make grey bg color for cells which are not editable and should not show value like here 16 for Margret Marmajuke age

Comment: You can add additional logic into the editable callback function to format the cell as you wish. I have updated my basic example to gray out the non-editable cell.